# How to do a registration in Simple Injector after a GetInstance call / Alternate solution?

Tags: c#, ioc-container, simple-injector

Consider the following example:

```
public class CommunicationClient : IClient
{
    public CommunicationClient(IServerSettings settings) { ... }
    // Code         
}

public class SettingsManager : ISettingsManager
{
    SettingsManager(IDbSettingManager manager)

    // Code
    public IDictionary<string, string> GetSettings() { ... }
}
```

**Problem**:
While performing registrations (using `SimpleInjector`), I need to provide values that are obtained from an instance of `SetingsManager` and fill `ServerSettings` instance (concrete type for `IServerSettings`) but if I call `GetInstance<ISettingsManager>` before registering `CommunicationClient`, it gives me an error that I cannot do that
**Error**: 
*The container can't be changed after the first call to GetInstance, GetAllInstances and Verify.*)

One solution could be to inject `ISettingsManager` as a dependency to `CommunicationClient` but I really don't want to pass it as it would provide more than required information to it.

**EDIT:** Container Registration

```
container.Register(typeof(ICommunicationClient), typeof(CommunicationClient));
ISettingsManager settingsManager = container.GetInstance<ISettingsManager>();

string url = settingsManager.GetSetting("url");
string userName = settingsManager.GetSetting("username");
string password = settingsManager.GetSetting("password");

container.Register(typeof(IServerConfiguration), () => 
      new ServerConfiguration(url, userName, password);
```

Any suggestions/alternative solutions on how to achieve above in a cleaner way? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the question to include container registration. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple Injector locks the container for further changes after its first use. This is an explicit design choice, which is described [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#container-is-locked). This means that you can't call `Register` after you called `GetInstance`, but there should never be a reason to do this. Or in other words, your configuration can always be rewritten in a way that you don't need this. In your case your configuration will probably look something like this:

```
var settingsManager = new SettingsManager(new SqlSettingManager("connStr"));

container.RegisterSingle<ISettingsManager>(settingsManager);
container.Register<ICommunicationClient, CommunicationClient>();

string url = settingsManager.GetSetting("url");
string userName = settingsManager.GetSetting("username");
string password = settingsManager.GetSetting("password");

container.Register<IServerConfiguration>(() => 
      new ServerConfiguration(url, userName, password));
```

There you see that `SettingsManager` is not built-up by the container. When using a DI container, you are not required to let the DI container build up every instance for you. Letting the container auto-wire instances for you is done to lower the maintenance burden of your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) and makes it easier to apply cross-cutting concerns (using decorators for instance) to groups of related classes. In the case of the `SettingsManager` and `SqlSettingsManager` classes, it is very unlikely that their constructor will change that often that it will increase the maintenance burden of your Composition Root. It's therefore perfectly fine to manually create those instances once.

Comment: @Steven I'm using a large number of AutoMapper Profiles, scattered around the code, which are registered at the composition root and may depend on some similar service. Should I create all the required services manually? I need to be able to easily change the settings manager.

Comment: @mrmashal please post a new question here on SO or on Github with some code to describe your use case. It's hard to give concrete feedback without such context.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, to create your `CommunicationClient` class, you need to pass information that are retrieved by calling a method on an instance of your `ISettingsManager`, but you don't want to pass the `ISettingsManager` as a dependency to your `CommunicationClient`?

One solution for that would be to create, and register, a factory that would have a dependency on `ISettingsManager` and that would have a `CreateClient` method that would return the configured client.

```
public class CommunicationClientFactory : ICommunicationClientFactory
{
   public CommunicationClientFactory(ISettingsManager settingsManager) {...}

   public CreateClient() {...}
}
```

This way your `CommunicationClient` is not dependent on the `ISettingsManager` and you have just this factory that does the work of creating your instance.

Edit:
An alternative, if you don't want to create a factory for this, would be to have your `CommunicationClient` object be created in an "invalid" state, and have a method that would set the settings and make its state valid.

Something like:

```
public class CommunicationClient : IClient
{
    public CommunicationClient() { ... }
    // Code

    CommunicationClient WithSettings(IServerSettings settings) { ... }
}
```

Of course, then you'd have to make sure that the user don't use it when the settings have not been passed yet, potentially sending an exception if that would be the case. I like this solution less, because it's less explicit that you NEED those settings to have your object in a correct state.

Comment: That would solve the problem, but isn't a factory an overkill here? Plus I'm using an IoC container(SimpleInjector) to obtain instances and manage their lifetimes.

Comment: And I would then have to pass the IoC container to the CommunicationClientFactory to create the instance.

Comment: I don't think passing the IoC container to the factory is a big issue, since it's just a factory, and you could also have more logic in it. With SimpleInjector I don't think there's an alternative, as there is no way to pass values in a constructor when using the anonymous factory (registering a `Fun<CommunicationClient>`)

Comment: I agree that injecting the container into a factory is not a problem, as long as the factory implementation is defined INSIDE the composition root. However, with Simple Injector you can register an anonymous factory (using Func<T>) without any problem, there's no limitation preventing you from doing that. I do however see the use of a factory as a useless extra layer of indirection in this case.

Comment: @Steven Yes, you can indeed use the `Fun<T>` factory, but you can't pass a parameter to the constructor of the class you're creating with those anonymous factory (at least I haven't found the way to do it). So if you really need to pass info to create the object, you don't have much choice but to create a factory as I shown in my sample code. If you have a better way I'm all ears though, because I have that kind of issue very frequently.

Comment: Both solutions seem acceptable but I would go for @Steven solution as in my case composition root and factory implementation would be in two different projects. Secondly, it seems simpler and avoids creating a factory for it.

Comment: @Gimly, perhaps I misunderstand you, but what you can do is this: `RegisterSingle<Func<string, IServerConfiguration>>(url => new ServerConfiguration(url, container.GetInstance<ISettingsManager>().GetSetting("username")))` or `RegisterSingle<Func<IServerConfiguration>>(() => { m = container.GetInstance<ISettingsManager>(); return new ServerConfiguration(m.GetSetting("url"), m.GetSetting("username")); })`.

Comment: @Steven wow thanks, I feel really dumb, but it never occurred to me that I could call `Container.GetInstace<T>()` into my lambda expression, so I was always stuck with passing parameters that were configured in the container... Woohoo refactoring ahead :)

Comment: @Gimly: Under the covers, your container is just a fancy dictionary, so if you register a `Func<T>`, you can resolve or inject a `Func<T>` :-)